# How to split strings in Prolog

Tags: prolog, split

I am trying to understand how user enter a sentence then will split in Prolog into separate words.
For example,
user enters this sentence: "computer consists of hardware"
I want to divide this sentence to: "computer", "consists", "of" and "hardware"

Can someone please explain how user enters sentence then split it in Prolog?

Comment: Please show the solution you've attempted and the specific problem you encountered.

Comment: At the very least, be a bit more specific about how you want to interact with the program: how do you call it? what output do you expect? what is valid input and what isn't? It might also help to figure out [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 4):

Swi-Prolog has a built-in predicate which makes this fairly easy:

```
?- split_string("computer consists of hardware", "\s", "\s", L).
L = ["computer", "consists", "of", "hardware"].
```

As far as I understand the third argument, +PadChars, in `split_string(+String, +SepChars, +PadChars, -SubStrings)`, it trims surrounding spaces.

For example, adding leading and trailing spaces in this example with +PadChars set to an empty string produces:

```
?- split_string(" computer consists of hardware ", "\s", "", L).
L = ["", "computer", "consists", "of", "hardware", ""].
```

Whereas setting PadChars to "\s" produces:

```
?- split_string(" computer consists of hardware ", "\s", "\s", L).
L = ["computer", "consists", "of", "hardware"].
```

But I'm not entirely clear if +PadChars serves any other purpose. Anyone know of any good examples to clarify it?

Answer (score 1):

If the sentence is contained in a list (i.e., [computer, consists, of, hardware]) then you could use:

```
split(L,Result) :- 
   splitacc(L, [], Result).
splitacc([], Acc, Result) :- 
   Result=Acc.
splitacc([H|T], Acc, Result) :- 
   append(Acc, [[H]], NewAcc), 
   splitacc(T, NewAcc, Result).
```

For instance:

```
?- split([a, computer, consists, hardware],L).
L = [[a],[computer],[consists],[hardware]] ?
```

Comment: thank you but I want in knowledge how user enters sentence then split using prolog for example in query screen:?-what is computer?user should answers on this question in this way: a computer consists of hardware.after user enters this answer,the prolog split to[a],[computer],[consists],[of],[hardware].